# Visual Studio 2013 add class from another project in solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am very new to visual studio and I can't seem to figure out how to reference a class that is in one project within another project.  I have tried:

I creating a reference to the project that has the needed class from the projects that needs the class.

I added an existing file (both c++ and header file to the project).

I added to the include directory in c++ additional includes but couldn't figure out how to include the .cpp file.

I just get the red underline under the `#include` with message it cannot open source file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Double check the paths and header file name. Also don't put .cpp file in another project, you only have to provide .lib to the linker.

Comment: If a class is shared between several projects, whats the best way to create it. I created it in the first project and then want to just use it in other projects.  Do I need to create a dll for it?

Comment: I'd most likely compile a library to include, but for VS you have to add the files to the project, it will not find them unless you do that OR you can setup the folders to include them, lastly you don't mention which version of VS your using..